# Pass mutlideimensional array to codeigniter view and display it in a table

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I'm developing a web application in codeigniter. I've a view which lists all complaints in a table. I'm passing an array of complaints from controller to the view. My array from controller looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [com_id] => 71 [engine_model] => 2 [assigned_to] => Sreejith KM ) 
[1] => Array ( [com_id] => 70 [engine_model] => KSERIES [assigned_to] => shaun ) 
[2] => Array ( [com_id] => 68 [engine_model] => fhg [assigned_to] => Din ) 
[3] => Array ( [com_id] => 69 [engine_model] => HA294 [assigned_to] => Don ) 
[4] => Array ( [com_id] => 64 [engine_model] => gshsh [assigned_to] => Don,Shaun ) )
```

I tried to display this array in view using foreach loop. But its not working. Corresponding rows are created but the data is not displayed in td.ie, blank rows are created. Can anyone suggest me a solution for this. Thanks in advance
Here's my code:

Contoller:

```
function re_assigncomplaint()
{
$data['returntech'] = $this->complaint_model->getTechnicians();
$data['returnitems']= $this->complaint_model->getallComplaints_reasign_test();
$data['page_title'] = $this->lang->line("reassign_complaints");
$this->load->view('commons/header', $meta);
$this->load->view('reasign', $data);
$this->load->view('commons/footer');    
}
```

View:

```
<table id="slData" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condensed" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th><?php echo $this->lang->line("complaint_id"); ?></th>
<th><?php echo $this->lang->line("engine_model"); ?></th>
<th><?php echo $this->lang->line("assigned_to"); ?></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
$i=0;
if(!empty($returnitems))
{
foreach ($returnitems as $return) {
?>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $return[$i]['com_id'];?>" name="idcheckbox[]" id="idcheckbox"></td>
<td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $return[$i]['com_id'];?></td>
<td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $return[$i]['engine_model'];?></td>  
<td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $return[$i]['assigned_to'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$i++;
}
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Model:

```
public function getallComplaints_reasign_test()
{
$myQuery = "select * from app_complaint where assigned_to != 'not assigned'";
$q1 = $this->db->query($myQuery);
if($q1->num_rows() > 0)
{
foreach (($q1->result()) as $row1)
{
$compid=$row1->com_id;
$engine=$row1->engine_model;
$tch = $row1->assigned_to;
$tch1=explode(',',$tch);
$tch2=array();
foreach($tch1 as $types)
{
$techname="select technician_name from technicians where id='$types'";
$q2 = $this->db->query($techname);
if($q2->num_rows() > 0)
{
$row2 = $q2->row();
$tch2[]= $row2->technician_name;
}
}
$tech=implode(',',$tch2);
$cmpl[]=array('com_id'=>$compid,'name'=>$cust,'com_type'=>$comptype,'engine_model'=>$engine,'assigned_to'=>$tech);
}
}
return $cmpl;
}
```

Comment: From where did you get `name` and `com_type` within `<td>` as you have shown within your array I can't seems those two values

Comment: Just a notice: Please use indents in your code (for your own good ;] )

Comment: remove `[$i]` in `$return[$i]['com_id'];` make it as `$return['com_id'];` and others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `foreach` loop and `$i` var together. You doesnt need `$i`. Use as `$return['com_type']` instead of `$return[$i]['com_type']`

```
foreach ($returnitems as $return) 
{
     $return['com_type'];
}
```

Or use `foor` loop like following:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($returnitems); $i++) 
{
     $returnitems[$i]['com_type'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Its working properly now.. :)